# Compare two dates in c# from Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, date

I have a column in database named tblreburial and a field reburialdate. The type is varchar and the format of the date is (yyyy/dd/mm).In c# I have this query:

```
 string query = "Select date_format(reburialdate,'%Y/%d/%m') as reburialdate from tblreburial";
```

in my While statement:

```
 while (myReader.Read())
{
  string date = (myReader["Reburialdate"].ToString())
  if(date == DateTime.Now.Tostring("yyyy/dd/MM")){
       //some statements
   }
}
```

I already tried many ways but I often get a String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: A little advice: Compare the date values (from `DataReader` & `DateTime.Now`) as `DateTime`, then do string formatting representation when they've same value.

Comment: Just typo :  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/dd/MM")

Comment: You can just get the date as a string from the database first, `string query = "Select reburialdate from tblreburial";`. Later, you can use [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) on the string, followed by a simple comparison.

Comment: For goodness sake, just remember about time zones and relativity of `.Today`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `dataReader` to DateTime and compare it with `DateTime.Today`

```
  var date = DateTime.Parse(myReader["Reburialdate"])
  if(date.Date == DateTime.Today) {
      //some statements
  }
```

You can also optionally pass format information to `DateTime.Parse`. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) is the MSDN documentation.

Comment: But I am not sure, How does `myReader["Reburialdate"].ToString()` throw this error : "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Can you debug what does `myReader["Reburialdate"]` return? What is stored in the DB for this column?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(myReader["Reburialdate"].ToString(), 
                              "yyyy/dd/MM", 
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

if(date.Date == DateTime.Today){
  //some statements
}
```